# Проверить наличие html элемента на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пишу скрипт для одной страницы, для конкретного элемента.

На другой странице он отсутствует, и вылазят ошибки.
Нашел способ обходить ошибки с помощью проверки наличия элемента таким образом:

```js
var el = $(".el").html();
if (!el) {
  console.log('Нет элемента');
} else {
  console.log('Есть элемент');
};
```

```css
.el {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #125415;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #43A047;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="el">Элемент</div>
```

Если if/else меня устраивает, то первая строка скрипта кажется длинной, может быть есть способ записать иначе?

Comment: `$('.el').length;`

Comment: @Евгений Шевцов . Дело в том что элемент может вернуть пустоту `''`, я бы вот так попробовал `if (typeof($(".el").text()) != undefined) {  console.log('Нет элемента'); }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно использовать [length](http://api.jquery.com/length/), чтобы увидеть совпадает селектор с чем-либо или нет

```
exist = $('#MyId').length;
```

Comment: можно спросить, а почему у пустого элемента свойство length равно единице?

Comment: @perfect `length` не возвращает количество символов внутри элемента. `length` возвращает количество элементов на странице с указанным селектором. А раз на странице элемент есть, даже пустой - соответственно и вернет единицу.......... например если создать пять дивов `<div class="el"></div>`  и написать `console.log($('.el').length);`  то выведется число 5. Ибо 5 элементов с указанным классом на странице присутствует точно. А что там внутри - уже дело десятое

Comment: если ищем элемент без атрибутов, работать будет?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, можете на примере моего кода написать проверку? у меня либо условие if else не срабатывает либо выдает ошибку если я вообще удаляю html элемент а как раз от ошибок мне и нужно избавиться

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вот как раз как в вашем комментарии и написал, и ошибка

Comment: А нет, сам накосячил все нормально работает)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов , действительно , я это свойство с нативным перепутал , надо было его назвать **count** чтоб путаницы не было.

Comment: @perfect без атрибутов, это например `<div></div>` ? Да, конечно. Ищем же по селектору в начале. А он может быть любой.

Answer (score 3):

Это делается вот так:

```
$("div").is(".el")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
el ? console.log('Есть элемент') : console.log('Нет элемента');
```

Это если, конечно, по одному оператору на вариант да / нет. Если больше - то ваша конструкция.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: console.log(el ? "есть": "нету")

Comment: так лучше - согласен